# Does a time-independent system have a time-independent Lagrangian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, time

Consider a Lagrangian $L:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose it has the property that if $\gamma:[t_1,t_2]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ solves the Euler-Lagrange equation, then (for any $a$) the path $[t_1-a,t_2-a]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $t\mapsto\gamma(t+a)$ solves it as well.

Does it necessarily follow that $L$ is independent of $t$?

Edit: as pointed out in a response, the answer to my question is 'definitely not,' since even if $L$ is independent of $t$, one may add to it a pure function of $t$, producing the same Euler-Lagrange equations.

So the better question is: if $L$ is as in my first paragraph above, then does there exist a second Lagrangian which is independent of $t$ and which produces the same Euler-Lagrange equations as $L$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative, if $L$ is time independent, e.g., $L+ a t$ produces the same equation of motion...

Comment: Thank you... I've edited the question to account for it.